# ORA-00913: "too many values".I am not sure where I should locate function and subquery

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I should see these columns in the result: "Job id, location id, location name, sales class id, sales class description, time id of the date promised for the job, time id of the last shipment date, order quantity in the job, sum of shipped quantity after job promised date, difference in business days between last shipment date and promised date"

But I am taking this error ORA-00913:  "too many values".
I am not sure where I should locate function and subquery !!
I will share my query and my function below.
In  Advance Thank you so much for your help.

Note: Function and select query of X1 Alias works normally.

´´´

```
 Select
Location_Id,
Location_Name,
Sales_Class_Id,
Sales_Class_Desc,
Date_Promised,
x1,
Busdaysdiff
 from (
   
Select  Loc.Location_Id, Loc.Location_Name, Sclass.Sales_Class_Id,
Sclass.Sales_Class_Desc, J.Date_Promised , (SELECT W_SUB_JOB_F.JOB_ID,
    MAX(actual_ship_Date)   AS Last_Shipment_Date,
    SUM ( actual_Quantity ) AS SumDelayShipQty
   FROM W_JOB_SHIPMENT_F, W_SUB_JOB_F, W_Job_F
   WHERE W_SUB_JOB_F.SUB_JOB_ID = W_JOB_SHIPMENT_F.SUB_JOB_ID
     AND W_Job_F.Job_Id = W_SUB_JOB_F.JOB_ID
     And Actual_Ship_Date > Date_Promised
   Group By W_Sub_Job_F.Job_Id ) as X1,
    Getbusdaysdiff(J.Date_Ship_By, J.Contract_Date) As Busdaysdiff
   From W_Job_Shipment_F Ship, W_Sub_Job_F Subj, W_Job_F J,W_Location_D Loc, 
W_Invoiceline_F Invo, W_Sales_Class_D Sclass, W_Time_D T
    WHERE subj.SUB_JOB_ID = ship.SUB_JOB_ID
     And J.Job_Id = Subj.Job_Id
     And Ship.Actual_Ship_Date > J.Date_Promised
     Group By Loc.Location_Id, Loc.Location_Name, Sclass.Sales_Class_Id,
Sclass.Sales_Class_Desc, J.Date_Promised
);

**function:

create or replace function getBusDaysDiff
(
-- Time_Id parameters
time_ID1 number,
time_ID2 number
-- time_id1 must be greater than time_id2
)
return number
IS

v_timne_ID1 integer;
v_timne_ID2 integer;
transTimeID integer;
difference integer;

Begin

v_timne_ID1 := time_ID1;
v_timne_ID2 := time_ID2;

if ( v_timne_ID1 = v_timne_ID2 ) then
return 0;
elsif ( v_timne_ID1 > v_timne_ID2 ) then 
transTimeID := v_timne_ID1;
v_timne_ID1 := v_timne_ID2;
v_timne_ID2 := transTimeID;
end if;

  execute immediate ' select count(*) from w_time_D where time_ID <= ' ||  v_timne_ID2 ||' and time_ID > ' || v_timne_ID1 into difference  ;

  if ( difference = '' or difference is null )then
    raise_application_error(-20011, ' An error occurred calculating the difference');
  else
    return  difference ;
  end if;
END;
```

Comment: Why are you choosing NOT to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: I do not know exactly why, I can say I am not used to it. Is that too important for a sql specialist or dba ? I can change my methods, if necessary.

Comment: @dwh_asil: Comma-separated joins (e.g. `from w_job_shipment_f, w_sub_job_f` are less readable and more prone to errors than explicit joins (e.g. `from w_job_shipment_f inner join w_sub_job_f on ...`) that were invented in 1992. Nowadays one shouldn't use that old comma syntax anymore. It is considered bad style for the mentioned reasons.

Comment: @dwh_asil . . . And I would add, that on a forum like this, it might dissuade some people from answering, since anyone who could help might start by rewriting your query.

Comment: ok. I will try to write JOIN scripts. thanks for your support and advice.

Answer (score 1):

Subquery must return exactly one value, not bunch of them (like yours). This one:

```
(SELECT W_SUB_JOB_F.JOB_ID,
    MAX(actual_ship_Date)   AS Last_Shipment_Date,
    SUM ( actual_Quantity ) AS SumDelayShipQty
   FROM W_JOB_SHIPMENT_F, W_SUB_JOB_F, W_Job_F
   WHERE W_SUB_JOB_F.SUB_JOB_ID = W_JOB_SHIPMENT_F.SUB_JOB_ID
     AND W_Job_F.Job_Id = W_SUB_JOB_F.JOB_ID
     And Actual_Ship_Date > Date_Promised
   Group By W_Sub_Job_F.Job_Id )
```

Illustration:

```
SQL> select deptno, (select empno, ename from emp where rownum = 1)  --> selects 2 columns (EMPNO, ENAME)
  2  from emp ;
select deptno, (select empno, ename from emp where rownum = 1)
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00913: too many values


SQL> select deptno, (select empno from emp where rownum = 1)        --> selects 1 column (EMPNO)
  2  from emp ;

    DEPTNO (SELECTEMPNOFROMEMPWHEREROWNUM=1)
---------- ---------------------------------
        20                              7369
        30                              7369
        <snip>
```

---

Perhaps you should just properly join those two tables to the rest of the tables in the main query.

Comment: Thank you for your help.But it works alone. The query produces 3 columns, and it reacts as it's supposed to be. do you think, is that the main problem ?

Comment: So what if it works alone? You aren't using it "alone" any more, so ... no use of it. It **must** return only one value (or no values at all), but can't return more than a single column nor more than a single row..